# How to insert only some fields to hive table, reusing existing table schema?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I already have a hive table, which is created before the tests e.g. it has columns A(String type),B(String),C(Number).

In the test case I only want to insert the test data, which will be queried later on, for example in columns A,B.

What is the best way to insert test data which has only data for columns A and B into already existing table which contains diff schema ?

I usually get something like schema mismatch errors, columns count mismatch etc errors when trying to do something like

```
val df = session.createDataFrame(rows, schema)
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).format("orc").saveAsTable(mytableName)
```

where `schema` is existing table schema `session.table(mytableName).schema` and `rows` are list of tuples with values for columns A and B.

Is there any appropriate API to do that ?

How to insert only some fields to hive table, reusing existing table schema ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append a new column to the dataframe that you want to write to table. Ex -

Let say you have data of two row - represented by two tuples:

```
val rows = Seq(("1", "2"), ("3", "4"))
val df = sc.parallelize(rows).toDF("A", "B")
val newDf = df.withColumn("C", lit(null).cast(IntegerType))
// Now newDf schema will be same as your table schema
println(newDf.schema)
println(session.table(mytableName).schema) 
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).format("orc").saveAsTable(mytableName)
```